# Election's page small css issue

Tags: bug, design, moderator-election

Let's have a look at this : [image]

Which was shot on my 1920*1200px monitor (last FF, zoom factor 100%)... Could we fix it?

It's displayed normally if I set the zoom factor to 80%

Comment: This happens when you scroll down past a certain point.